# Embed a specific point on my own map on my website

Tags: maps, share, embed

I have my own Google Map which has app. 200 points of interest (Campsites). I want to embed a map on my website for a specific point on my own map ie, and individual campsite. Can anyone help please? I have a Google Map API and can see how to embed the whole map, but not a lat/long of a specific location within my map.

Comment: What, if anything, have you already tried? SO won't write your code for you.

Comment: I've tried pretty much everything I can think off; I have a Google API and have read the developer documentation but can't find a specific answer to this question. I have no desire for SO to write my code - I'm just looking for a push in the right direction.